# Writing many stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, query-optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to write a long procedure which generates a report for a company.
Since report involves multiple data to be fetched i have written many small procedures to fetch the different records . 
Is it the write approach to write many sub programs in the main program and calling them in the main program?

please help or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: there is no particular limit to the generation time of report but it is expected it should fetch data in an hour or two since it is an offline report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really go wild (**) and build a 'tree' of stored procedures each calling the other one I don't see any problems with this. There might in fact be benefits to this as

- it's easier to maintain smaller pieces of code
- (re)compilation of smaller stored procedures is going to be faster

**: There is a 'limit' in MSSQL in that the stack is limited to 32 levels. That is, if procedure1 calls procedure1_1 and that procedure calls procedure1_1_1 and that one calls another etc... you'll get an error when you get over 32 calls 'deep'. Calling multiple stored procedures sequentially isn't a problem though.

The only thing to keep in mind is the context of the variables/temporary tables you're using. If you want to pass values around you'll need to use parameters. (using `OUTPUT can be useful to keep track of a @rowcount variable for instance).